# Move current line to end of previous line

Tags: vim

This happens a lot to me.

```
foo = 
  bar
```

I want to easily move the content of the bar-line behind the equal sign.
I know that I can do this if I am on the bar line:

```
^^dEk$p
```

but this feels clumsy, is there a shorter/more elegant way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

say your cursor is on `bar` line, you can do:

```
kgJ
```

to have:

```
foo =  bar
```

Check help doc for `J, gJ and :join`

I also wrote a [Join plugin](https://github.com/sk1418/Join), can do negative count (will work for your example), reverse join and lot more.

Comment: Thank you, this is nearly what I wanted. The problem is that the spaces infront of 'bar' will remain there. After looking at the doc of J I found that simply doing J at the foo line does what I want.

Comment: `J` will add/remove space between two lines, `gJ` won't. You can take the one you need.

Comment: can you expand what those letters are for?

Comment: @yantaq Please see `:h J`.